# Why I can't create function with return "Array" instead NSArray in Swift?

Tags: arrays, xcode, nsarray, swift2

**Swift 2.0 - Xcode 7.2**

I would like to create one function like this:

```
func returnExampleArray() -> Array {

    return ["term1","term2"]

}
```

With the return of the function as "Array" default in Swift 2.0, but the Xcode 7.2 only allow return with NSArray, like this:

```
func returnExampleArray() -> NSArray {

    return ["term1","term2"]
}
```

Why I don't can use Array instead NSArray?

Comment: What do you mean by "only allows"?  What does it say?

Comment: The Xcode show error but I do not know I am procedure with this:
"Reference to generic type 'Array' requires argments in '<>'... "

Comment: Well perhaps you could quote any error messages in the future?  You have your answer, however (see below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fogmeister's answer is correct but it doesn't really tell you why.

The `Array` type is a generic type. You can't simply return an `Array` because Swift needs to know what you can put in that array. Your first function should be written:

```
func returnExampleArray() -> Array<String> 
{
    return ["term1","term2"]
}
```

But, of course there is special notation for arrays. Where you would put `Array<T>` where T is some type, you can put `[T]` instead, which is syntactic sugar for the original version, and that is where Fogmeister's answer comes from.

`NSArray` is an Objective-C type and is not generic (but you can almost think of it as being like `Array<AnyObject>`) That's why your second example works. However, a lot of stuff goes on behind the scenes in that the array `["term1","term2"]` has to be converted into an `NSArray` of `NSString`s before it is returned.

Comment: Thanks for explain minutely.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to return an `Array` in Swift would be to write it like this...

```
func returnExampleArray() -> [String] {    
    return ["term1","term2"]
}
```

or

```
func returnExampleArray() -> [TypeHere] {    
    return [.. objects of correct type here..]
}
```

If you're using other object types in the array.

Comment: @MartinSt77 happy to help. Make sure to accept the answer that solves your problem. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to poach he acceptance. Have upvoted as compensation :)